# Visual Studio Android building assembly files into app

Tags: android, visual-studio, assembly, ld, unix-ar

We've got a Visual Studio Android solution with (among others) a static library project that contains functionality implemented in assembly. Like:

```
my.S -> libMine.a -> libMyApp.so
```

Some hoops (below) have already been jumped through, to get it to compile. Then, the linking of the main app shared library project fails (on both architectures that we care about - x64 and arm64), with undefined references to the functions that are implemented in [the] assembly [file].

It appears that Visual Studio (or its Cross Platform Mobile Dev / Android plug-in) doesn't handle assembly file project items quite correctly - treated as C/C++ Compiler files, it'll error out on the first dot character (i.e. in `.text`); and the Microsoft Macro Assembler is "not supported on this platform". So I looked into setting up a custom build step, with the following command:

```
$(ClangToolExe) %(FullPath) --target=$(ClangTarget) -g -o $(IntDir)%(FileName).o
```

This will preprocess, compile and link - but with the wrong linker: instead of the one for the particular Android toolchain, it'll go for the one in my MinGW install, which doesn't recognise the emulation mode - anyway, that's not the location of my NDK toolchain.

We can skip the linking of the object for now (add `-c` to the above command). Much to our dismay, the resulting object file still doesn't get added to the static library, as confirmed by `{Rest of the toolchain path}ar t libMine.a`. And indeed, the library will have undefined symbols for our functions, as shown by `{Rest of the toolchain path}objdump -t libMine.a`.

Let's add the object file to the resulting library quite manually, as a post build step. Command:

```
$(ToolChainPrebuiltPath){Rest of the toolchain path}ar.exe ru $(TargetPath) $(IntDir)my.o
```

`objdump -t libMine.a` will now show that we've got the symbols. There is however also the *UND*efined pair.

Fast forward:

- Adding `my.o` with `ar rub otherObjectThatReferencesMyFunctions.o libMine.a`, to have the good symbols show up before the undefined ones doesn't make a difference.
- Linking my compiled assembly file with a second custom build step, `$(ToolChainPrebuiltPath){Rest of the toolchain path}ld.exe $(IntDir)%(FileName).o -o $(IntDir)%(FileName).o` doesn't make a meaningful difference.
- Running the linker again *on the static library*, as a second post-build step `$(ToolChainPrebuiltPath){Rest of the toolchain path}ld.exe $(TargetPath)` doesn't make a meaningful difference.
- The last two steps result in a warning about a missing symbol _start (entry point?). I'm guessing this is in reference to linking *an executable*, which we don't want.

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve those undefined references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to have worked was to:

1, Make sure that the extension of the assembly file is `.S`, i.e. capital S. This is one of the few instances I've found, where the case of a filename matters on Windows.

2, Configure the project so that the assembly file is built with `clang.exe {full/path/to/assembly.S, i.e. %(FullPath)} -c --target=$(ClangTarget) -g -o $(IntDir)%(FileName).o`. In the case of VS Android, we need to specify the build output separately, which is the `$(IntDir)%(FileName).o` part all over again.

3, Run `ar` as a post build command: `{correct toolchain}/ar.exe rus $(TargetPath) {output from assembly compilation}`, *for each assembly file*.

One thing this solution is lacking is detecting [a lack of] changes, meaning that the assembly file will be rebuilt on each compilation, and everything that depends on it.

Comment: gcc/clang work the same on Windows as on Unix/Linux.  `clang -c foo.S` runs it through the C preprocessor before feeding it to the assembler.  `.s` doesn't.  Use `.S` for hand-written asm source, and leave `.s` for compiler-generated asm (like from `gcc -save-temps` or `gcc -S foo.c`.)